# Native iOS WebRTC only seems to connect on Offer

Tags: swift, xcode, webrtc

I am building the iOS client for a WebRTC based solution and we got stuck fixing the older project that was abandoned by the previous developer. In order to start from a "known good" I created a clean application forking off [a demo by Stasel](https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC-iOS). Then, I would switch between our signaling server and his simple locally running example server.

I started noticing that it always seemed to connect on the Offer, never on Candidates. However the rest of the infrastructure uses trickle and there's a chance their Offers do not contain Candidates.

Is there some kind of switch that allows trickle to work? I see some documentation for the web clients but can't find anything for the native iOS client.